# Outer not working in R

Tags: r

I have 3 vectors x, y and z. I want to create a matrix whose (i,j)^th entry will be sum((x[i]*z+y[j])^2)

I'm trying to use `outer` for this but I'm getting an error. Here is an example:

```
x=y=1:10/10
z=1:10
outer(x,y,FUN=function(x,y,z) sum((x*z+y)^2),z)

Error in outer(x, y, FUN = function(x, y, z) sum((x * z + y)^2), z) : 
  dims [product 100] do not match the length of object [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the following summation:

```
\sum_{k=1}^n [(x_i*z_k + y_j)^2]
\sum_{k=1}^n [(x_i*z_k)^2 + 2*x_i*z_k*y_j + y_j^2]
\sum_{k=1}^n [(x_i*z_k)^2] + 2*x_i*y_j*\sum_{k=1}^n [z_k] + n*y_j^2
```

So an efficient way to proceed would be to compute the first term with an outer product between `x` and `z` and to compute the second term with an outer product between `x` and `y`:

```
outer.sol <- function(x, y, z) {
  n <- length(x)
  xmult <- rowSums(outer(x, z, function(x, z) (x*z)^2))
  matrix(rep(xmult, n), nrow=n) +
    outer(x, y, function(x, y) 2*sum(z)*x*y) +
    matrix(rep(n*y^2, each=n), nrow=n)
}
outer.sol(x, y, z)
#         [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]   [,9]  [,10]
#  [1,]   5.05   6.45   8.05   9.85  11.85  14.05  16.45  19.05  21.85  24.85
#  [2,]  17.70  20.20  22.90  25.80  28.90  32.20  35.70  39.40  43.30  47.40
#  [3,]  38.05  41.65  45.45  49.45  53.65  58.05  62.65  67.45  72.45  77.65
#  [4,]  66.10  70.80  75.70  80.80  86.10  91.60  97.30 103.20 109.30 115.60
#  [5,] 101.85 107.65 113.65 119.85 126.25 132.85 139.65 146.65 153.85 161.25
#  [6,] 145.30 152.20 159.30 166.60 174.10 181.80 189.70 197.80 206.10 214.60
#  [7,] 196.45 204.45 212.65 221.05 229.65 238.45 247.45 256.65 266.05 275.65
#  [8,] 255.30 264.40 273.70 283.20 292.90 302.80 312.90 323.20 333.70 344.40
#  [9,] 321.85 332.05 342.45 353.05 363.85 374.85 386.05 397.45 409.05 420.85
# [10,] 396.10 407.40 418.90 430.60 442.50 454.60 466.90 479.40 492.10 505.00
```

While you could use a looping solution like `mapply` to compute each element individually, which would make your code a good deal easier to read, note that this will be much slower than the fully vectorized solution with `outer`:

```
mapply.sol <- function(x, y, z) {
  n <- length(x)
  matrix(mapply(function(i,j) sum((i*z+j)^2), rep(x, n), rep(y, each=n)), nrow=n)
}

# 1000 x 1000 case
x <- y <- z <- 1:1000
all.equal(outer.sol(x, y, z), mapply.sol(x, y, z))
# [1] TRUE
system.time(outer.sol(x, y, z))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.060   0.001   0.060 
system.time(mapply.sol(x, y, z))
#    user  system elapsed 
#  18.522   1.986  20.432
```

From the comments it appears the true function is more complicated than the quadratic one included in the question, so the provided `mapply.sol` with your function is the (rather slow) way to go.

Comment: I just used sum((x*z+y)^2 as an example. In reality I have to use sum((x*z+y)^n for many higher/non-integer powers n ... so this method will not work ...

Comment: @AbhirupDatta I've included a working example with `mapply` in my solution, which will work in your case. Note that in general computing a matrix one element at a time is slow (as I demonstrate in this answer), but this is what you're stuck with.

Comment: Thanks for the mapply solution ... it is as slow like using a for loop which I didnt want to use as my vectors x,y, z are large ... any idea how to trick outer to work for this ?

Comment: @AbhirupDatta No, because you have a general function to apply for each pair `(x[i], y[j])`, namely `sum((x[i]*z + y[j])^k)`. Unfortunately there's no free lunch -- either you identify a mathematical fact that can help you like I did at the beginning of the question or you use a looping solution like `mapply`. Note that mathematical facts can often be very useful in speeding up code -- the one I used in the quadratic case led to a 300x speedup for 1000-length vectors.